# Setup a separate view for traffic to a subfolder in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

We just launched our website in Arabic language and would like to setup a separate view in Google Analytics to just view the traffic and all the other data for Arabic.

The Arabic language is rendered on a subfolder.

For instance: www.examples/ar/ launches the Arabic version of the website.

I setup a new view in Google Analytics to just show the Arabic data. I did the following but it's not returning any data. It's been more than a week and everything shows 0.

[image]

I've google analytics setup for the root domain and it's working fine. I also know for a fact that there is traffic coming to the arabic version of the website by going in Behavior > Site Content > All pages and then typing "/ar/" in search to see all the pages in arabic that are getting traffic.

Answer (score 1):

the filter that you have applied not seems correct. Check this post, it has clearly defined how to check traffic for sub domain in Analytics: https://www.techwyse.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/subdomain-and-cross-domain-tracking-in-universal-analytics/

Comment: mine is a subfolder, not  subdomain. Not sure how what you shared is relevant.

Comment: Yes you have a subfolder and the process described in that post can be implemented similarly on a subfolder